# Python27: Checking to see if user input is correct. When select Yes, returns name correctly. When select no, return is 'None'

Tags: python-2.7

I'm writing a small program to auto fill forms.  I want to do checks along the way to make sure the user input is correct and give the opportunity to make a correction if they misspelled something.  The output goes to a file called SN.dbf.

ETA:  SN stands for Serial number.  I generate an SN for the file and the number itself is in the filename.

My code:

```
def Name(SN):
    verify = False
    fname = raw_input('What is your first name? ')
    lname = raw_input('What is your last name? ')
    name = fname+' '+lname
    print name
    check = raw_input('Is this correct?  yes/no')
    if check.upper() not in {'YES','Y'}:
        verify = True
    else:
        return name

    while verify:
        verify = False
        Name(SN)
name = Name(SN)
with open(SN+'.dbf','w') as mfile:
    mfile.write('Name: '+str(name)+'\n')
```

When I run through it and select yes, it writes the name to the file just fine.  But when I select no and go through it again, it returns 'None'  I just need to know what I'm doing wrong.  Still pretty new to python...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user first answers "no", you enter the `while verify` loop and call `Name` again, recursively. You continue to recurse like this until the user replies `yes`. Then the innermost call to `Name` returns, and so on up the stack.

The problem is, when you call `Name` recursively, you don't capture its return value. Replace this:

```
while verify:
    verify = False
    Name(SN)
```

with:

```
while verify:
    verify = False
    return Name(SN)
```

Add a "return" statement.

Better yet, structure your code more conventionally:

```
def Name(SN):
    while True:
        fname = raw_input('What is your first name? ')
        lname = raw_input('What is your last name? ')
        name = fname+' '+lname
        print name
        check = raw_input('Is this correct?  yes/no')
        if check.upper() in {'YES','Y'}:
            return name
```

Comment: Happy to help. Will you hit the checkmark to accept my answer as correct, or is there anything else I can help you with?

Comment: You got me going well on my way.  :)  I clicked the check mark for your help.  And thanks again.